# expand/collapse horizontally window/Hbox on button click in ZK

Tags: zk, hbox, zul

I want to expand & collapse hbox/window horizontally(east/west) not vertically(north/south) on image button click in ZK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ZK layouts will help you to achieve your task.

[ZK Layouts demo example](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/layout/business_portal)

Comment: Thanks Subodh!!
I found some specific demo.I will share later